# Flask - Use the same view to render a search form and then search results

Tags: python, search, flask

I want to have a search form to query the database and display the results from the search below it. I don't want any confirmation warning to appear when refreshing the page. Also I want to know if this can be done with a single view function as all the tutorials I've seen use more than one. Like [this one](https://dzone.com/articles/flask-101-how-to-add-a-search-form) and [this one](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-x-full-text-search-legacy).

This is working but it shows a warning that asks for confirmation when clicking the refresh button on the browser:

main.py

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = SearchForm()
    query = form.data['search']
    if query != '':
        results = Foo.query.filter(Foo.name.like('%'+query+'%')).all()
        return render_template('index.html', form=form, query=query, results=results)
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class SearchForm(FlaskForm):
    search = StringField('search', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

templates/index.html

```
{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
  <form style="display: inline;" action="{{ url_for('index') }}" method="post" name="search">
    {{ form.search(size=20) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
  </form>

  {% if results %}
    <h1>Search results for "{{ query }}":</h1>
    {{ results }}
  {% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock page_content %}
```

This is what I would like but it gives a `page not redirecting properly error`:

```
    @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = SearchForm(request.form)
    if form.validate:
        session['query'] = form.data['search']
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    if 'query' in session:
        results = Foo.query.filter(Foo.name.like('%'+session.get('query')+'%')).all()
        return render_template('index.html', form=form, query=session.get('query'), results=results)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have a single function to render the search page and then after `form.validate_on_submit()` query the database and return the results. For the search results add an [if statetment](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#if) to display them on the same template as the search form.

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    form = SearchForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        search_term = form.query.data
        results = Foo.query.all()
        return render_template('search.html', form=form, results=results)
    return render_template('search.html', form=form)
```

search.html

```
{% block content%}
<form method="post">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.query }}
    {{ form.submit }}
    {% if results %}
        {{ results }}
    {% endif %}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It works, but it displays a confirmation warning when refreshing.

Comment: what's a confirmation warning?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWqNt.png  This happens
because browsers repeat the last request they have sent when they are asked to refresh
the page. When the last request sent is a POST request with form data, a refresh would
cause a duplicate form submission, which in almost all cases is not the desired action. It is fixed with a post/redirect/get pattern.

Comment: You'll have to change the [pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) so that it redirects to a different view i.e. `def show_results():`. It's also the reason you aren't able to share a url i.e. `example.com/search?query='some text'`.

Comment: Something is missing from this example. Following it exactly renders an empty page with no visible input field to perform the search query on.

Comment: @mikkokotila if it doesn't render it could be your Jinja template.

Comment: @roy I tried by exactly copying the example you have provided.